# Display circumflex over 2 characters in HTML

Tags: html

I need to display a circumflex over more than one character. Using

```
  NX&#770;
```

results in a circumflex over just the X, NX̂. What is the markup to display a circumflex over both characters?

Comment: Which language is that from?

Comment: The NX-hat symbol is from a mathematical model.

Comment: Have you tried using jsMath or MathML or something? I know, that may be an overkill for a single character, but if you're displaying parts from math models, you might have more use for that.

Comment: My app will eventually display complete formulas, so bringing in a math formatting library is not overkill. It appears MathJax has replaced jsMath. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible in UTF-8. In Latex, you can do `\widehat{nx}`.

An option would be to do `<span class="widehat">nx</span>` and then have a CSS rule that puts a circumflex over the top as a background image. However, that wouldn't be semantic, and you'd lose the information if someone copied and pasted it.